# Is there a way to force links to open in external browser instead of Facebook in-app-browser?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I think I already know the answer - "no"!

Basically the facebook in-app-browser has some bugs on various platforms and I want to show a button that enables user to open in external browser. But sounds like it is not possible from reading previous answers.

This sucks, does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: I hate that browser!

Comment: None of the previous answers work for me. Not in ios8 at least.

Answer (score 2):

The app decides how to open links so you cant force it to use an external browser through your code. It can be changed in the app settings but that won't help you.

You can try to detect the Facebook browser through the user-agent and then throw a popup or something like that asking the user to click the 3 dots at the top right and then "open with chrome" or whatever the iPhone equivalent is.